# Can't install Laravel 4 Grunt

Tags: php, sass, laravel-4, less, gruntjs

I'm getting this error when running this command: `sudo php artisan grunt:setup`

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 and using laravel 4.

I have no idea what to do now...

```
mikkel@mikkel-K53SV-Linux:/var/www/forum$ sudo php artisan grunt:setup
A gruntfile.js or package.json file already exist and will be replaced. Do you want to continue? [yes|no]yes
Node and NPM are installed. Continue...
Do you require CSS preprocessing? [yes|no]y
Which CSS preprocessor do you require? [less|sass|stylus]l
I did not recognize that preprocessor. Please try again. [less|sass|stylus]less
package.json & gruntfile.js successfully created!
Installing / updating required grunt plugins...
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-compress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-concat
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-cssmin
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-jshint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-less
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-sass
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-stylus
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-livereload
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-uglify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-watch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-notify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-phpunit
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-clean
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-cssmin

npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: grunt-contrib-cssmin@'>=0.6.1- <0.7.0-'
npm ERR! No valid targets found.
npm ERR! Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:488:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:438:17)
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:415:44)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:408:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:147:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs.js:230:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /var/www/forum/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-32-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/forum
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: grunt-contrib-cssmin@'>=0.6.1- <0.7.0-'
npm ERR! message No valid targets found.
npm ERR! message Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/www/forum/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

I just had to re-install node.js.